# What's the difference between Component.requestFocus and manually focus

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

Both invoking Component.requestFocus() and manually focusing on a component (for example, use keyboard or mouse to focus on it) will trigger a FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED.

I am listening to the AWT events.

My question is :

How could I know the FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED event is from invoking Component.requestFocus() or from manully focusing on it by mouse/keyboard?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't...

Comment: Mostly because both triggers will post a `FocusEvent` onto the Event Queue.  No information about how the event was raised is maintained...

Comment: Is there any workaround for it? I really need to know what generate the event.

Comment: The question there is, why?  A `focusGained` event is, well, a `focusGained` event...

Comment: if you think you need to know the difference, you should reconsider your setup - typically it shouldn't matter. If it seems important in your context, please elaborate (you can edit the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

when you use requestFocus you try to gain focus on that component, but regarding documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus()

it is better to use requestFocusInWindow(boolean)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow(boolean)

---

For checking whether a component has gained focus, you have to implement FocusListener and override the following methods

```
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    displayMessage("Focus gained", e);
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    displayMessage("Focus lost", e);
}
```

Comment: So now, how does the OP know which method caused the `focusGained` event to be triggered?